# Entity Framework 6 - Add parent with children which contains other children

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a problem with add object to DbSet.

```
class Word
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Inflection> Inflections {get;set;}
}

class Inflection
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public virtual Word Word {get;set;}
}

class Translation
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public virtual Word Word {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Sentence> Sentences {get;set;}
}

class Sentence
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public virtual Translation Translation {get; set;} 
}
```

I do this:

```
DatabaseContext.UserWord.Add(entity);
DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

Here is my configuration of relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Word)
    .WithMany(x => x.Translations);

modelBuilder.Entity<Inflection>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Word)
    .WithMany(x => x.Inflections);

modelBuilder.Entity<Sentence>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Translation)
    .WithMany(x => x.Sentences);
```

I try to create Word object:

```
{
    "Id": "GUID"
    "Translations": [
        {
            "Id": "GUID",
            "Sentences": [
                {
                    "Id": "GUID",
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Inflections": [
        {
            "Id": "GUID",
        }
    ]
}
```

but "DatabaseContext.SaveChanges()" throws exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Sentence_dbo.Word_WordId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "tempDatabase", table "dbo.Word", column 'Id'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Everything is ok for below Word object:

```
{
    "Id": "GUID"
    "Translations": [
        {
            "Id": "GUID"
        }
    ],
    "Inflections": [
        {
            "Id": "GUID",
        }
    ]
}
```

What do I do wrong?
Can you help me?

Comment: Something is wrong - the error message indicates `"FK_dbo.Sentence_dbo.Word_WordId"` FK, but there is no such relationship in what you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your `sentence` model has changed because it's having foreign key to `word` when it should reference to `translation`, please try to run `add-migration` to check if to see the changes and `update-database` (that if you're using code-first migration)

Comment: Thank you! I had 1 migration and added another one. Second migration didn't remove `Word_WordId` from DbMigration file. So I removed all migration files and created Init migration and now it works.